# Truth of Logic converse for identities and using terms in formal derivations,

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the book im self studying when the author talks about ordered pair equality he writes $(a,b) = (c,d) \to (a = c \wedge b = d)$
and asserts that the converse is a truth of logic i.e $(a=c \wedge b=d) \to (a,b)=(c,d)$

while thinking about this I thought about what rule of logical identity is he referring to, and how could we use it as a rule of inference in derivations? Going by Suppes introduction to logic book (as that is my basic background so far) It seems clear to me that he is going by what he writes as the principle of extensionality:

> if $x=y$ then whatever is true of x is also true of y and vice verse

corresponding to this the Rule of Inference needed is what he writes as:

> **Rule Governing Identites:**
> If $S$ is an open formula, From $S$ and $t_1 = t_2$, or From S and $t_2=t_1$, we may derive $T$, provided $T$ results from $S$ by replacing one or more occurrences of $t_1$ in $S$ by $t_2$. Moreover the identity $t=t$ is derivable from the empty set of premises

Thus in a derivation according to the **Rule Governing Identites** we may proceed (informally): let $S$ be $(a,b) = (a,b)$ and suppose that $a=c \wedge b = d$ thus applying the **Rule Governing identities** twice we infer $(a,b) = (c,d)$

In order for a formal derivation to go along these lines (as stated just above) to be correct we must be sure $(a,b)=(a,b)$ is in fact a **open formula**

Suppes gives the definition of an **open formula** as a formula with no quantifiers where the usual definition of a formula is given recursively, we know equality $a=b$ where a, b are **terms** is a formula. But the **Main** question of this post is:

> Why is $(a,b)$ a term? Furthermore as the other example beneath why is the *unit set* {x} a term?

Here is Suppes definition:

> a **TERM** is an expression which either names or describes some object, or results in a name or description of an object when the variables in the expression are replaced by names or descriptions.

My thinking was well $(a,b)$ is a term since if we replace $a$ with $1$ and $b$ with $2$ we get an expression which names the ordered pair $(1,2)$

Does this seem correct?

This question was inspired by the "truth of logic" converse for equalities as another example of this "truth of logic" converse $a=b \to ${a}$=${b} but once again in a formal derivation if we want to apply the **Rule Governing Identities** we must be sure that {a} is a term and if it is we may proceed by the above.

Comment: Quite long... but in a nutshell you have to apply the equality axiom for substitution for terms: $x=y \to f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: The set notation $\{ x\}$ is a function symbol that gives a "name" of a set.

Comment: The converse to the ordered pair equality as being stated as a truth of logic, is actually in Suppes logic text. Yet he gives no such Axiom for such a substitutition, hence all I could come up with to use in a formal derivation is what I wrote informally using the Rules Governing Identities.

Comment: You can check, I’ve been following his book and his axiomatic set theory closely. Of course to prove the converse for ordered pairs. We can translate ordered pairs in terms of sets, and then translate equality of ordered pairs (as sets) with the logical connective “or” and then apply the Rule Governing identities to the formula with “or” in it and then The Rules Governing Identities is justified  However say Ordered pairs is treated as a primitive object, then the above informal derivation is the best I can do.

Comment: As an example say that $A$ and $B$ are sets and $A=B$ Informally to prove that $x ∈ A \iff x ∈ B$ We let S be $x ∈ A \iff x ∈ A$ and then since this is a open formula and $x ∈ A$ is a predicate we can substitute B for A in one side of the equivalence using the Rule Governing Identities. However things somehow get trickier when we discuss ordered pairs and identities.

Comment: Right, in his Axiomatic set theory book the converse to ordered pair equality is not even stated! While in his logic book he says “it’s a simple matter of the logic of identities” thus I’m assuming we must be able to justify with the system he gives.

Comment: Having the Pairs axiom we introduce the function symbol $\{ A,B \} =y \leftrightarrow \ldots$ using the machinery of extension by definition (see Suppes on definition).

Comment: Yeah, I understand this.

Comment: See George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 2: Set Theory (Cambridge UP, 2003)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Lectures_in_Logic_and_Set_Theory_Volume/nparMXao59QC), **Ch II.3. The Language of Axiomatic Set Theory**, page 106 and **III.2.5 Definition (Set Terms)**, page 126.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two principles dominating our conception of identity, called *Leibniz's laws* (unfortunately, they are usually referred to as singular, though they are separate laws). One of them is *the indiscernibility of identicals*, which is represented in symbolic form as

$$\forall x\,\forall y\,\big(x=y\rightarrow \forall F(Fx\leftrightarrow Fy)\big)$$

This principle states the *logical identity*: For any $x$ and $y$, if $x$ is identical to $y$, then $x$ and $y$ share any of their properties $F$; hence, they are *numerically identical*, for they count as one.

The other one is *the identity of indiscernibles* (some refer only to this by Leibniz's law), which is represented in symbolic form as

$$\forall x\,\forall y\,\big(\forall F(Fx\leftrightarrow Fy)\rightarrow x=y\big)$$

This principle states the *qualitative identity*: For any $x$ and $y$, if $x$ and $y$ share any of their properties $F$, then $x$ is identical to $y$. This is *not* a logical principle; because $x$ and $y$ may be qualitatively identical, but *numerically distinct* according to the theory the statement is grounded on, i.e., the theory may not distinguish $x$ and $y$ by their properties, but count them as two.

$(a, b) = (c, d)\rightarrow (a = c\wedge b = d)$ by the definition of ordered pair. In case that $(a = c\wedge b = d)$, what can be said about $a$ is *ipso facto* about $c$, and so for $b$ and $d$. Hence, we have

$$(a, b) = (c, d)\leftrightarrow (a = c\wedge b = d)$$

as is the case in general for the strictly formal definitions in mathematics. *In abstracto*, mathematical objects are conferred existence by their properties. Thus, the coincidence of logical and qualitative identities is a rule, rather than exception in mathematics. For example, let us consider an algebraic structure $X$. Suppose $X$ is a group under multiplication. Then, we can list its properties and there is nothing above and over them to its identity. As we acquire more information about $X$'s properties, that it is abelian, that it is finite, and so on, we may make it more concrete. However, at each stage, $X$'s identity is constituted merely by the properties. When a structure $Y$ comes to be identical to $X$ (we leave such algebraic issues as isomorphism aside), $X$ and $Y$ share their identities, numerically and qualitatively.

In the reverse direction, suppose we are given the following (composition) table for a structure $X$:

$\begin{array}{c|c c c}
* & 1 & \omega & \omega^{2}\\
\hline
1          & 1 & \omega & \omega^{2}\\
\omega     & \omega & \omega^{2} & 1\\
\omega^{2} & \omega^{2} & 1 & \omega\\
\end{array}$

Then, we can make out that $X$ is a finite abelian group. The more information we acquire, that $w$ is cube root of $1$, the more concrete it becomes, while its identity is always bounded by its properties.

The upshot is that two mathematical objects $x$ and $y$ are always (it may not be of convenience or practically feasible in some cases, though) intersubstitutable whether they are logically or qualitatively identical.

An ordered pair is a mathematical object composed of two mathematical objects $x, y$ together with a relation between them and represented by $(x, y)$. A set $\{\ldots\}$ is another example for mathematical object.

When considering the syntactic notions of formal languages of logic, it may be helpful to draw analogies between them and natural language. Terms function like names, and formulas function like sentences of natural language. A *logical name* (i.e., what we should understand by "name" that corresponds to "term") is a syntactic element that designates an object. So, a logical name may be a noun by grammar as well as a description (consider a compound term $f(t_{1},\ldots, t_{n})$).

A term can be open or closed in a similar vein as formulas. In an open term, at least one variable occurs, a closed term is either a constant defined in the language or composed of constants. If $a, b$ are variables, then $(a, b)$ is an open term, and $(1, 2)$ is a closed term. Clearly, a closed term designates a specific object. An open term designates an object in a generic sense.

Note that closure difference does not interfere with identity operations. For example, $x + 2$ is an open term and $5$ is a closed term. If $x + 2 = 5$, then we can substitute the terms $x + 2$ and $5$ one for another so long as there is no illegitimate binding of $x$.

In the light of the foregoing discussion, let us examine Suppes' *Rule Governing Identities*:

$t = t$ is derivable from empty set of premisses as any theorem is; it comes with the *logical identity* predicate denoted by $=$.

$S$ and $T$ are substitution instances of each other and logically equivalent, because $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ are identical. As Suppes notes on p. 103, the use of open formulas is "[t]o avoid lengthy restrictions regarding the presence of quantifiers"; there is nothing deeper about it.

Comment: Does this also answer the question i just posted as to why examples like $A \cap B$, $A \cup B$, $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$, and $\{a,b\}$ are Terms?

Comment: Relevant, but it would be better to treat your recent question separately.

Comment: Can you please look at it! its really bugging me! Because i feel the theory he is introducing is inconsistent if this question can't be answered.